# jQuery Dialog closes immediately

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery dialog box that closes immediately upon opening. It is set to a button located in a template field of a GridView.

**My JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtBeginDate").datepicker();
        $("#txtEndDate").datepicker();

        $("#response").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Equifax Response"
        });

        $("[id*=lnkEquifaxResponse]").live("click", function EquifaxResopnse() {
            $("#response").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**My relevant GridView markup:**

```
<div id="Gridview">
    <asp:GridView ID="grClientTransactions" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ResponseXML"
        EmptyDataText="Record not found." EmptyDataRowStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
        EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Bold="true" CssClass="mGrid" 
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="grClientTransactions_PageIndexChanging" 
        onrowcommand="grClientTransactions_RowCommand">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEquifaxResponse" runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="False"
                        CommandName="EquifaxResponse" 
                        Text="View" 
                        CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="Equifax Response">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEquifaxResponse" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("ResponseXML")%>' >
                    </asp:Label></div>                            
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                          
        </Columns>
```

**My div that displays a label with an assigned string from CodeBehind:**

```
<div id="response">
    <asp:Label ID="lblDialog" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: Are you wanting to post back to the server? If not, you just need to render a regular <a href="javascript:void"></a> item. Or asp:HyperLink instead.

Comment: please check the Error Console in Mozilla by using key combination "ctrl+Shift+j", and let us know the error, if there any.

Comment: There is a postback to to get the contents of the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method has been deprecated and removed in version 1.9 and has been replaced with the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Therefore, replace this:

```
$("[id*=lnkEquifaxResponse]").live("click", function EquifaxResopnse() {
    $("#response").dialog("open");
});
```

with this:

```
$("[id*=lnkEquifaxResponse]").on("click", function EquifaxResopnse() {
    $("#response").dialog("open");

    return false; // Prevents the postback
});
```

---

You can do this in a different manner:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[id*=lnkEquifaxResponse]").on("click", function EquifaxResopnse() {
            $("#lblDialog").empty();
        });

    if($("#lblDialog").text() != "")
    {
        $("#response").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

Comment: I added `return false` to prevent the default action of a button click.

Comment: That solved the immediate close, but know the dialog box isn't displaying the contents of the div. Prior to adding return false i would get the desired result with the exception of the window closing immediately. Any thoughts on the new issue?

Comment: Is that button calling any method on code behind to fill that `lblDialog` inside the `#response` div? Where and when do you fill that label's value?

Comment: yes it calls a method to format an xml document and then places the result in the label

Comment: So, that's the problem. You need to postback to process this. You could instead use AJAX to do this asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks Leniel I believe you are onto it, I need to figure out how to do the Ajax now.

Comment: Or implement a different logic as I described in the updated answer.

Comment: Thats got it, but of course now there is new problem. Evey time it posts back after the initial dialog box is opened, it opens on postback again. Also everything on the screen is rendered smaller. You have been very helpful, I don't want to consume to much of your time. I'm gonna work on it a bit and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. Maybe going with the AJAX is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

If `lnkEquifaxResponse` is causing a postback, then that is the problem. The dialog is being re-rendered as closed after the postback.  Are you using UpdatePanels or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The live method is deprecated and it should be like this instead and you should add an event argument to pass into the callback. You also need to add preventDefault(); which prevents the default behavior of the anchor tag

```
  $("[id*=lnkEquifaxResponse]").on("click", function EquifaxResopnse(ev) {
        //prevents the default behavior of the anchor tag causing the page to postback or re-render
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#response").dialog("open");
    });
```

You can also instead add at the end of your callback

```
return false;
```

but this becomes quite buggy in IE and ev.preventDefault() checks for IE and whether or not to add return false or returnValue. IE7 likes to see this and won't work otherwise.

```
ev.returnValue = false;
```

The source for preventDefault() looks like this in jQuery

```
preventDefault: function() {
    this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

    var e = this.originalEvent;
    if ( !e ) {
        return;
    }

    // if preventDefault exists run it on the original event
    if ( e.preventDefault ) {
        e.preventDefault();

    // otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false (IE)
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
},
```